# Problem in Serial Communication between nodeMCU and arduino

Tags: serial, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to send some messages from nodeMCU to Arduino using Serial communication (aka UART). Following is the code on nodeMCU side:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "my-ssid"; // SSID i.e. Service Set Identifier is the name of your WIFI
const char* password = "my-pasword"; // Your Wifi password, in case you have open network comment the whole statement.

int ledPin = 13; // GPIO13 or for NodeMCU you can directly write D7 
WiFiServer server(80); // Creates a server that listens for incoming connections on the specified port, here in this case port is 80.



     void setup() {
          Serial.begin(115200);
          delay(10);

          pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

          // Connect to WiFi network
          WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
          //Trying to connect to wifi
          while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
            delay(500);
          }
          Serial.println("$Wifi Connected#");
          server.begin();
        }

        void loop() {
          // Check if a client has connected
          WiFiClient client = server.available();
          if (!client) {
            return;
          }

          // Wait until the client sends some data
          while(!client.available()){
            delay(1);
          }
          // Read the first line of the request
          String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
          client.flush();

          int value = LOW;
          if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1)  {
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
            Serial.println("$Led High#");
            value = HIGH;
          }
          if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1)  {
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
            Serial.println("$Led Low#");
            value = LOW;
          }

          // Return the response
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
          client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
          client.println("<html>");

          client.print("Led pin is now: ");

          if(value == HIGH) {
            client.print("On");
          } else {
            client.print("Off");
          }
          client.println("<br><br>");
          client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON\"\"><button>Turn On </button></a>");
          client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF\"\"><button>Turn Off </button></a><br 
            />");  
          client.println("</html>");
          delay(1);
        }
```

Following is the code on Arduino side:

```
String msgFromNodeMCU;
void setup() {
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  msgFromNodeMCU=Serial.readString();
  Serial.println(msgFromNodeMCU);
}
```

which was working fine until I modified that code to:

```
String msgFromNodeMCU;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  msgFromNodeMCU=Serial.readString();
  delay(10);
  String wifi_connected="$Wifi Connected#";
  String led_High="$Led High#";
  String led_Low="$Led Low#";
    if (msgFromNodeMCU.equalsIgnoreCase(wifi_connected)) {
      Serial.println("Wifi Connected");
      delay(10);
    }
    if (msgFromNodeMCU.equalsIgnoreCase(led_High)) {
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    }
    if (msgFromNodeMCU.equalsIgnoreCase(led_Low)) {
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    }
}
```

With this code, I see no "Wifi Connected" message on my Serial monitor and there is no response on pin 13. This implies msgFromNodeMCU is not heard. What can I do for msgFromNodeMCU to be heard? Any sort of help is highly appreciated. :D

Comment: You have two `delay()`, 10 seconds each. While interrupts still works when you `delay()`, communications input buffer are limited in size. If you don't collect the information timely, buffers will be overwriten, information will be lost. Replace `delay` with `millis()` as shown in the BlinkWithoutDelay sketch that comes with your IDE.

Comment: +Look Alterno Removing `delay()` or adding `millis()` was not helpful. It would be nice if as soon as any message comes to the Serial buffer, it interrupts the target device (arduino in this case). Is there a way to create such interrupt?

Comment: Serial will not interrupt you. You have to `poll` Serial frequently.

Comment: Serial is ESP or USB?

Comment: @Juraj  Serial is ESP. Not USB

Comment: My question was educational. you write "I see no 'Wifi Connected' message on my Serial monitor". how is Serial Monitor connected? I am sure it is USB.